# Is it possible to show Recyclerview from two lists of different types?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Android Studio 3.6

To show list on screen (Activity) I use  `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` and `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.`

Nice it's work fine.

But now I need to show two **different** lists (different type of items) in one screen. And scroll this both lists as one list. The elements of these two lists will be mixed up. Must be sorted **by date**.
E.g.:

```
list1.item1_type1
list2.item1_type2
list2.item2_type2
list1.item2_type1
list1.item3_type1
list1.item4_type1
list1.item5_type1
list2.item3_type2
```

Is it possible to show **TWO lists** in one `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Why don't you just append second list with the first one & send to the adapter?

Comment: Use NestedScrollView > ViewGroup > RecyclerView

Comment: @someuser this two different lists has different type of items.

Comment: If you need to show different types of items you definitely should use `getItemViewType` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem is to sort out the lists based on date, but the problem is those are of different types. So we need to fix it by using another type/class that will have data of both class. Then we'll be able to sort our new list of combined type.

Let's recreate the problem first: 
Suppose we have two Types:

```
data class DataType1(var title: String, var date: Date)
data class DataType2(var title: String, var date: Date, var someOther: String)

val list1 = mutableListOf <DataType1> ()
val list2 = mutableListOf <DataType2> ()

list1.add(DataType1("Data 1", Date("01/01/2012")))
list1.add(DataType1("Data 2", Date("01/01/2013")))
list1.add(DataType1("Data 3", Date("01/01/2014")))

list2.add(DataType2("Data 21", Date("01/01/2022"), "Other"))
list2.add(DataType2("Data 22", Date("01/01/2010"), "Other"))
list2.add(DataType2("Data 23", Date("01/01/2005"), "Other"))
```

At this point we'll introduce new Type which is `FixTypes` here.

```
class FixTypes(private val data1: DataType1?, private val data2: DataType2?) {

    lateinit var date: Date
    lateinit var title: String
    var someOther: String? = null // those are not common field can be null

    init {
        if (data1 != null) {
            date = this.data1.date
            title = this.data1.title
        } else if (data2 != null) {
            date = this.data2.date
            title = this.data2.title
            someOther = this.data2.someOther
        }
    }
}
```

Then make a new list:

```
val fixedList = mutableListOf<FixTypes>()

list1.forEach {
    val ft = FixTypes(it, null)
    fixedList.add(ft)
}

list2.forEach {
    val ft = FixTypes(null, it)
    fixedList.add(ft)
}
```

As we've copied both of lists data to NewType we'll sort it:

```
fixedList.sortByDescending { it.date }

fixedList.forEach {
    Log.d("TAG", it.date.toString())
}
```

Our sorted list is:

```
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2022
Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2014
Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2013
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2012
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2010
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2005
```

Now we'll modify out `Adapter`s source list type to our newly created type. 
That's all.

Oh another thing to mention, using two `recycler` view *won't* work, because how will you mix up items?

Answer (score 1):

As Elias commented above, wrap two RecyclerViews in a NestedScrollView.

Setup and implement 2 different RecyclerViews. In the XML layout they are one on top of the other, but inside a a NestedScrollView. The effect will have both lists on top of each other, scrolling as one.

Comment: But I need items of this two list to be mixed. E.g. list1.item1, list2.item1, list2.item2, list1.item2. Is it possible?

Comment: This is a different question, but if you want to alternate items in one list, create a custom adapter that takes 2 lists. In the onBindViewHolder of your adapter, you need logic to determine which list and item you populate the list Item with.